# Python: Swap Blue and Yellow colour values in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageCms, ImageFilter, ImageChops

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

%matplotlib widget
```

Hello

I found the following function for inverting colours in images:

```
ImageChops.difference(image)
```

The problem is this inverts the whole image. Now I'm asking myself wether there is a way to only invert specific colours in an image. I want to swap yellow and blue colour values in an image and do not know how to do it using the packages above.

Is there a way to that using the mentioned packages?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as yellow color values in PIL Images.

Comment: Maybe you can add representative input images and corresponding expected output images to your question.